# Matrix inequality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ , invertible and monotone matrices and  we are given that $A\geq B$ holds ,which mean that $a_{ij}\geq b_{ij}$ for all $i,j=1,...,n$.We have to prove that $A^{-1}\geq B^{-1}$ .

The statement that we have to prove $A^{-1}\geq B^{-1}$ it true ?? Because all the ways that I tried to prove it , in the end  I get the opposite inequality $B^{-1}\geq A^{-1}$.

Which seems to be true if  we think that

$A\geq B\Rightarrow A^{-1}A\geq A^{-1}B\Rightarrow I\geq A^{-1}B\Rightarrow B^{-1}\geq A^{-1}$

Comment: How are you imposing an order on the matrices?

Comment: What is a motone matrix? An array with soul?

Comment: I don't know how you wrote $A\geq B\implies A^{-1}A\geq A^{-1}B$. But, if there is an inequality then $B^{-1} \ge A^{-1}$ seems to be more probable. For that, consider $A = 2 B$.

Comment: A matrix $B$ is said to be monotone if it's inverse $B^{-1}$ is positive, (all the entries are positive). $A\geq B$ is given by the question and with the knowledge of that inequality we have to prove that $A^{-1}\geq B^{-1}$.

Comment: I thought it was a recording company...

Comment: If anything, clearly the reverse inequality is to be proved, and is correct.